# How can I automate bringing in specific fields from excel into word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a few Microsoft word files that I need to create on a same project. I would like to make an excel file with all the common fields and bring them into each of the word files.
Is there anyway I can do this? Below are some of the sample fields. I need to use these same fields on 2+ different word files. So, I want to know if there is an easy way to bring them into multiple word files.
This is how I thought of creating an excel file and bringing these fields into both word files.

```
Case ID: ####
Case Name: XXXX
Business Owner: XXXX
Due Date: MM/DD/YYYY
Issue Owner: XXXX
Issue Description: XXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is called Mail Merge

Your data points are in separate columns of an Excel spreadsheet with headings for the columns that give field names. Each row after that, if you have multiples, has an identifier or key which may be a phone number, or a last name.

The basics are in this [Microsoft Documentation on Mail Merge using an Excel Spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3).

People think of Mail Merge as being a way to do multiple copies of one document as in a mass mailing. It also works for one-of (at a time) of multiple primary merge documents. I've been using this method for more than thirty years to prepare draft pleadings for court cases where there are multiple documents that will use the same data.